# How to calculate age using datetimepicker?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to figuring out how to calculate the age of user in my flutter application. What I want is only valide user which are have a min age of 18. Heres my code

```
String _date = "Please pick Age";

  Widget _buildage() {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
      Text(
        'Enter Age',
        style: kLabelStyle,
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      Container(
        decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        height: 70.0,
        child: Container(
          child: TextFormField(
            initialValue: "haaas",
            validator: (val) {
              if (val.isEmpty) {
                return 'Enter yout Age';
              }
              if (val.length < 4) {
                return 'Enter a username minimun 4 chars long';
              }

              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() => age = val);
            },
            onTap: () {
              DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                  theme: DatePickerTheme(
                    containerHeight: 210.0,
                  ),
                  showTitleActions: true,
                  minTime: DateTime(2000, 1, 1),
                  maxTime: DateTime(2022, 12, 31), onConfirm: (date) {
                setState(() {
                  _date = '${date.year} - ${date.month} - ${date.day}';
                });
              }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
            },
            readOnly: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.date_range_rounded,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 28,
              ),
              hintText: " $_date",
              hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

So in the TextformField I wanna check also if user has a minimum age of 18.Hope anyone can help. If you need more information please leave a comment .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  //the selected date
  var userSelectedDate = DateTime(1999, 12, 26);

  //the duration difference form the selected date to now in days
  var days = DateTime.now().difference(userSelectedDate).inDays;

  //the duration difference in years (the current age)
  var age = days ~/ 360;
```